# What are the extra parameters in Facebook's static link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cdn

Note: I realise it's a bit unconstructive and I'm not sure whether this is the best place to ask. Please advise me of improvements.

You know you can get the link to a facebook photo (or video) by right clicking and selecting 'view image'. The result is a link like this:
[`https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10933156_10203060010133603_822853448_n.jpg?oh=dba759bccf50f4ae560b537fa9c00220&oe=54B175C2&__gda__=1420909750_63a4972d4a589cd466a895e276fc47eb`](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10933156_10203060010133603_822853448_n.jpg?oh=dba759bccf50f4ae560b537fa9c00220&oe=54B175C2&__gda__=1420909750_63a4972d4a589cd466a895e276fc47eb)

And it's a public link, that everyone can access.
However, I kept this link in my open tabs for a few days, and later on it didn't work anymore. I went back to the photo on facebook, and did 'view image' again. I got the following link: [`https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10933156_10203060010133603_822853448_n.jpg?oh=70ebf67dc3467b8005e2127c4c2a176e&oe=54B8B602&__gda__=1421384950_1bad935cd7546335702cca5849a374fe`](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10933156_10203060010133603_822853448_n.jpg?oh=70ebf67dc3467b8005e2127c4c2a176e&oe=54B8B602&__gda__=1421384950_1bad935cd7546335702cca5849a374fe)

Note the two links are identical up to the `.jpg` part, but they differ in the parameters.

Is there any way to find out what those parameters are and to generate them? Namely, if by having the link up to `.jpg` I can use some logic to get the right parameters to view the content (like profile id, date, encoding etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an updated link of a image, you'll need to get it via Graph API using the object id.

Example: `https://graph.facebook.com/<object_id>?fields=images&access_token=<access_token>`

This call will return an JSON object with all the sizes of images and updated links:

```
{
  "height": 1365, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/10904088_10152667653291915_7973131445285931474_o.jpg", 
  "width": 2048
}
```

You can get the object id via Graph API or the link of the image on the web interface. Example of url: `https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152667653291915` - The `fbid` parameter is the object id you need.

Comment: cool! this is kinda what I was looking for. Unfortunately, the image comes from a message attachment and, AFAIK, those are not accessible yet/anymore see [this thread] (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/153137724878722?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52517d949d48d3494815922).

Answer (score 0):

No. Those are CDN links and they expire. And it is by design they expire so no you can't generate the rest of the url

Comment: I never noticed it before. Do you know when they expire ? I mean, I have other links that are older and haven't expired yet. Also, why would this design decision be made?

Comment: Because you shouldn't store the urls